# NodeJS Body Parser throwing: Unexpected _

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, body-parser

Recently my NodeJS API has been throwing an extremely strange error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token _
    at parse (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /var/www/html/node/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
    at invokeCallback (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
    at done (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/var/www/html/node/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:308:7)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

As this doesn't point to any file I have outside of node_modules, I'm very confused as to what could be causing this error. I have values such as creation_timestamp and _id but I have never yet had trouble handling those.

If anyone has a solution or even some way to get more info out of this I would greatly appreciated it, I'm at my wits end with this.

EDIT: This is the stringified JSON I'm posing:

```
{"meeting_id":"5755d81869996f6e4cea47ea","type":"delete_entry"}
```

Comment: Have you tried updating your npm package to the latest version for body-parser?

Comment: That is because you are using `bodyparser.json()` and posting not-valid JSON to request handler url.

Comment: I've posted the raw JSON from Fiddler.

Comment: Input that you posting is valid and cannot cause error that you provided, logic inside uses regular expression to find the first character using this `/^[\x20\x09\x0a\x0d]*(.)/.exec('{"meetingid":"5755d81869996f6e4cea47ea","type":"delete_entry"}')[1]` and this returns `{` for your input, look https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/lib/types/json.js#L79

Comment: Any ideas on how to hunt down what is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was due to KendoUI Scheduler and the way its transport endpoint works. You need to stringify explicitly before sending requests through your Scheduler constructor. In Scheduler.dataSource.transport I added:

```
parameterMap: function (data, op) {
    return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

Now it works.